# Android animation-list with shape darwable not working properly

Tags: android, animation, shapes, animationdrawable

I'm trying to do an Animation between different image resources. Therefor I'm using the frame animation.

listanimation.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/music_playing_indicator_1"
        android:oneshot="false">
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_1" android:duration="500" />
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_2" android:duration="50" />
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_4" android:duration="50" />
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_5" android:duration="50" />
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_2" android:duration="80" />
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_1" android:duration="150" />
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_3" android:duration="600" />
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/animation_2" android:duration="250" />
</animation-list>
```

animation_1 - 5.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <size
        android:height="2dp"
        android:width="2dp" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```

I just adjust the height form 2dp to 4dp to 6dp to 8dp to 10dp.
animation_1 2dp
animation_2 4dp
animation_3 6dp and so on.

After I run the animation, of course I set the background of the imageview to my animation-list drawable.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.Animation);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img
                .getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();
```

But here is the Problem the animation seems not to animation as it should. it's slow sometimes it's not animating at all.

If I do the same thing with real .png files. animation_1 -5.png with different heights It works Perfectly. I'm confused now. Is there any limitation of using shapes in animation-list?

The reason why I'm using the shapes its easier to target different devices with different screen sizes an so on.

I'm thankful for any help...

Cheers Alex